# crystal reports trimming strings

Tags: crystal-reports

I’m new on crystal reports and don’t have much knowledge of programming. I’m looking for a formula that will separate the notes (example: To Syd+We miss you+From Bill&Pat) into 3 different field. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want them to be separated?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I'm looking for formula to keep what's before the + symbol. 
Example: To Syd+
Expected result is : To Syd
Thanks for you help, understanding and patience.

Comment: you want to concatinate the string by removing the symbol in between?

Comment: Good morning, No I'm looking to keep the first part of the string before the plus symbol and delete after the plus symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
local stringVar subject := 'To Syd+We miss you+From Bill&Pat';
local numberVar location := instr(subject, '+');
if location > 0 then
 left(subject, location)
else
 subject;
```

I have hardcoded the string to be modified, but you can replace it with {table.field}

Also, if there will definitely always be + you can simplify things by removing the if.

Answer (score 0):

a note that Lee's answer will get you the leftmost bit of text only.

instr(subject,"+") returns the location of the leftmost presence of +

left(subject,location) pulls out a chunk of subject of 'location' number of characters

if you then wanted to fish out the second and third bit, you could do this:


local stringvar subject := "string1+string2+string3";

local numberVar location1;

local numberVar location2;


location1 := instr(subject, "+"); 

location2 := instr(location1+1, subject, "+");

/////this instr only starts to look from location1 for the next leftmost + and I'll show below how you can use


(  if location1 > 0

    then left(subject, location1-1) 

/////use Lee's 'left' command to bring up the first bit, I added the minus1 so that the actual + would not show

    else "missing first +"  )

+chrw(13)+  //I was displaying this on screen so I added a ENTER, you can get rid of this line

(  if location2 > 0 

/////error checking is sanity-saving sooner or later

    then 

    (

        mid(subject, location1+1, location2-1-location1) 

/////pulls a chunk from within subject, starting at location1+1 [to get past the + at location1 itself], 

/////going rightward to grab 'location2-1-location1' characters 

/////(play a few times with the +1/-1 to get hte idea.

/////try it with a two-character seperator, say "To john12Hello12From jane", helped me get my head straight

        + chrw(13)+   //again, this is just for my proofing

        right(subject, length(subject)-location2)

/////pulls a chunk from the right of subject, of size 'length of subject' minus location2,

/////so everything from the end until hit that +

    )

    else "missing second +"  )

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you for helping us! You guys are the best!